# Spring Security. Доступ к контроллерам по авторизации

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth2

Каким образом защитить контроллер? Т.е. есть авторизация OAuth2, в заголовке отдаю токен Bearer и хочу получить доступ к api/user, если нету токен или же истёк срок жизни, то бросить ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

**security-context.xml**

```
...
<beans:bean id="apiEntryPoint"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<security:http use-expressions="true" request-matcher="regex"
  entry-point-ref="apiEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/user/.*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
...
```

Неавторизованные пользователи будут получать 403-ю ошибку.